# Can't install mysql-server on Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, python, dpkg, mysql

Firstly I wanted to say that I am sure this is a well known error and I did a lots o search to fix this. But none of them worked. When I type `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, I got this error:

```
Exception: cannot get content of ubuntu-drivers-common
error running python rtupdate hook ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apparmor:
apparmor depends on python3:any; however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apparmor (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.7:
mysql-server-5.7 depends on apparmor (>= 2.10); however:
Package apparmor is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3
apparmor
mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server
dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this? Thanks a lot,

Comment: Did you try with sudo apt `update && sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt -f` before `sudo apt install mysql-server`?

Comment: @pa4080 Yes I did, and I got exact same error when I type 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade'

Comment: Ops, I've missed install above - `sudo apt install -f` (that means `--fix-broken`), you can also try and the `--fix-missing` option.

Comment: @pa4080 And it gave exact same error as well. :(